# Animation node search library present in geometry nodes problem

Tags: add-on, geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

When I reimported animation nodes to the current version of blender (3.4.1), the geometry nodes and animation nodes library combined in the geometry nodes search box. In the animation nodes tab, the search box doesn't have geometry nodes like it should, but I get the error when adding a node from the search box: AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.node.add_and_link_node" error, could not be found

Comment: Report it as a bug via Help > Report a bug in Blender. There are no developers here.

Answer (score 2):

This is not isolated to *Animation Nodes*, many other add-ons (like *Serpens* and *MTree*) who provide their own nodetree editors and custom nodes have the same problem because apparently the Python template for creating custom nodes Blender provided [was erroneous and they inadvertently copied the mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb0h7.png).

*Animation Nodes* seems to have fixed that particular problem [with this commit](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/commit/d302171a4aa8f0ed5a050520327ff2c6ad2228e0). Any other bugs you encounter should be reported there.